# Сослагательное наклонение в относительных предложениях

Tags: синтаксис, сослагательное-наклонение

В одной работе написано:

> *Основной семантический компонент, который влияет на выбор
>   гипотетического сослагательного наклонения в придаточном предложении,
>   - это пресуппозиция несуществования определяемого объекта. Поэтому важным фактором использования сослагательного наклонения является
>   наличие в главном предложении отрицания.*

Не могли бы Вы помочь мне понять пожалуйста, почему в следующих примерах используется индикатив:

> (a) В семинаре не могут принимать участие те, кто не **знают** испанского
>   языка.
>
> (b) Ему не нравятся женщины, которые не **умеют** готовить.

В моем языке предикат относительного предложения стоял бы в сослагательном наклонении. Если соблюдены факторы из теоретического фрагмента (главное предложение отрицается; речь идет не о конкретных участниках / женщин а о возможных), почему в таком случае не используется сослагательное наклонение? Пробую заменить в примерах индикатив через сослагательное наклонение: на мое ухо звучит коряво, но не нахожу причину.

Спасибо!

Comment: Правильно: кто (ед. число) не **знает**.

Comment: М_Г: спасибо! че́стно говоря́ только предложение (b) сама придумала. предложение (а) украла из flyer, который делали русские доценты в нашем университете =)

Comment: Вот что дает сайт http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/710-22_dopolnenie_i_ego_raznovidnosti.html

Обычно не допускается смысловое согласование и при местоимениях кто, что, а также производных от них (кто-то, некто и др.). Независимо от реально выражаемой ситуации местоимение кто требует сказуемого и определения в форме единственного числа мужского рода, а местоимение что – в единственном числе среднего рода:

Comment: Кто-то из нас совершил этот проступок; Это сделал тот, кто побывал здесь раньше; Что-то большое и тёмное стояло в дальнем углу зала.

При подлежащем кто множественное число сказуемого может быть использовано в том случае, когда в придаточном предложении именная часть составного сказуемого выражена существительным во множественном числе:
Те, кто двадцать лет назад были школьниками, сейчас вершат судьбу страны. 

Но ведь это не Ваш случай, так что переспросите доцентов, откуда у них взялось мн. ч.

Comment: Надо бы сказать: Не может принимать участие тот, кто не знает испанского.

Comment: http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/783-33_nekotorye_osobennosti_soglasovaniya.html

Comment: М_Г: thank you very much, i'll pass this information on to my lecturers! =)

Answer (score 1):

Надо определить **наличие гипотетического значения** в заданных предложениях.

(a) Настоящее время, семинар проходит сейчас. Поставлено условие:  **В семинаре не могут принимать участие те, кто не знает испанского языка.** Это изъявительное наклонение, здесь нет гипотетического значения.

А вот сослагательное наклонение: **В семинаре не могли бы принимать участие те, кто не знал бы испанского языка.** Здесь гипотетическое значение присутствует, но что оно означает? К примеру, семинар только готовится и такое условие предполагается.

Или другая ситуация: Вы думаете, что он не знает испанского языка? **Но в семинаре не могли бы принимать участие те, кто не знал бы испанского языка.** Думаю, что он знает язык. Это гипотетическая ситуация.

(b) **Ему не нравятся женщины, которые не умеют готовить**. Изъявительное наклонение, никаких гипотез.

**Ему бы не нравились  женщины, которые не умели  бы готовить.** Что это? Автор создает характер героя?

Или: Ты думаешь, она ему нравится? Мне кажется, **ему бы не понравилась женщина, которая не умеет готовить**. Это гипотетическое значение.

Comment: Arina: спасибо за ответ но извините, че́стно говоря́ не поняла что Вы хотите сказать. сравниваю например с предложением: "Нет ни одной женщины, которой бы он не нравился". Имеем отрицание в главном предложении, рассматриваются все потенциальные женщины а не одна конкретная, сле́довательно сослагательное наклонение в относительном предложении. Почему в таком случае в (а) и (b) с отрицанием используется индикатив, если участники в (а) и женщины в (b) не конкретные, а предполагаемые? При всем этом сослагат. н. звучит weird в (а) и (b) и индикатив звучит weird в "Нет ни одной женщины, которой ..."

Comment: Пока очень коротко. Как мне кажется, в русском языке нет жесткой привязанности к формальным схемам. Я могу сказать категорично: Нет такой женщины, которой он не нравится (= из его окружения). Но могу сделать это высказывание только предположением:  Не такой женщины, которой он не нравился бы  (=имея в виду любую женщину).